# CSS - это язык программирования или разметки?

Tags: css3

CSS - это язык программирования или разметки?  Или как еще понимать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS -  формальный язык описания внешнего вида документа, написанного с использованием языка разметки (c) [Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).Этим и все сказано!

Нет конечно же это не язык программирования.

Answer (score 2):

Разметки...А человеческим языком - создан для придания уникальности тегам HTML и вообще.
С Css  очень многие программисты(даже профи) испытывают трудности с ним. Так как CSS один из немногих языков который почти невозможно (в некоторых ситуациях) предугадать как он поступит - в одном и том же коде при разных ситуациях - он может поступить по разному.

Грех называть Css языком программирования. Я представляю что бы программист например на C++ сделал с человеком который назвал мастера CSS или HTML  - программистом :DDDD.

Answer (score 0):

Это формально CSS язык форматирования. Есть много примеров игр на чистом CSS. Мне кажется его можно использовать как язык программирования только в узкой плоскости. Последние спецификации CSS наглядно показывают безграничность работы с DOM. Потенциал селекторов тоже очень высокий. Нету привычных все типов дынных и привычных условий с операторами. Потому его нельзя назвать типичным языком программирования. Имхо css давно вышел за рамки языка стилей.